# userId: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 64e310ad9d821c557b4f9bc7 " (type string) at path "userId" because of "BSONError"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm passing the "id" to the hidden input value in EJS but I am getting a bson error, The data is still being stored properly in the database but the error is shown in the EJS file

form.ejs file where the error is coming

**form.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     
     <form action="/createform" method="post">
         <label>Email:</label>
         <input type="email" name="email"/><br>
         <label>Phone no:</label>
         <input type="number" name="number"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="userid" value=" <%= result._id %> ">
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

user controller file from where the form.ejs is called

**userController.js**

```
exports.postAddAnotherUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name
  const age = req.body.age
  try {
   
    const result = await User.create({
      name: name,
      age: age,
    });
    console.log(result._id.toString());
    const value = result._id
    console.log(typeof(value))
    res.render("form", {result:result })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

createForm is exectued perfectly

**formController.js**

```
exports.createForm = async (req,res,next) => {
    const userid = req.body.userid
    const email = req.body.email
    const number = req.body.number
 
    console.log(userid);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(number);


    try {
        const result = await Form.create({
            userId: userid, 
            email:email,
            phone:number
            
        })
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect("/form")
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

exports.form = (req,res,next) => {
    res.render("form")
}
```

**formModel.js**

```
const FormData = new scheme({
    userId:{
        type: scheme.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    phone:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
```

I have tried all possible way but I think it is stemming from EJS as the data do get stored in the db but the error is still being thrown.
we are doing json.toString but in the value prop of input field it is showing that we are passing objectId.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**we provide you a image where you see the error**
**write in formController.js at last line **

`res.render("form", {result:result })`

**Image link **[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USIfw.jpg

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you